# A medieval poem by Pietro Crinito

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

In searching the phrase *gravis ambitus* (an attempt to render "tense/harsh/difficult atmosphere"), I found an [interesting poem](https://books.google.com/books?id=0RQOAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA416&lpg=PA416&dq=%22gravis%20ambitus%22&source=bl&ots=m8AE-DHIYv&sig=ACfU3U0Uw3EIk_r90s7subglklueLHAiBQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiGvpazz6H6AhWohf0HHScxDLMQ6AF6BAgOEAM#v=onepage&q=%22gravis%20ambitus%22&f=false) by Pietro Crinito ([Latin ode on his long sickness and approaching death](https://books.google.com/books?id=0RQOAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=snippet&q=This%20poem%20of%20Crinitus%20is%20given%20in%20the%20appendix%20No.%20XXI&f=false)). just before the end we read this part:

> Non ille cuiquam flebilis occidit,
> Quem vitae honestas, et fidei decor,
> Inter sacrarunt numina Caelitum,
> Expertem gravis ambitus.

I can't make sense of this part grammatically (*cuiquam* dative of occidit? *numina* the subject or object of *sacrarunt*?, *Expertem gravis ambitus*?) nor, I can decipher the overall meaning of this part.

My primary focus in this question is to understand what is *gravis ambitus* (if it indeed the case that those are to be taken together). but a translation/explanation of the grammar of this part would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Understanding theological poetry like this requires a lot more than knowledge of grammar. There is a whole ideological culture behind these kinds of writings which has its own symbology and idioms. So, unfortunately, you have to know or figure out the different relevant pieces of Catholic ideology to be able to parse poetry of this kind.

---

In the first sentence *cuiquam* is the agent of *flebilis*. So, the literal meaning is "That one dies not lamentable to anyone," or more figuratively as we would say in English "He dies not lamented by anyone".

*Quem* refers to the subject of the previous clause (ille). So, the subject of the previous clause is the object of the next clause (because *quem* is accusative).

*numina* refers to the divine powers of heaven in Christian theology

*caelus* is the sky. Caelus is the ancient personification of the sky. In Christian theology *Caelitum* is the personified abode of the sky, the "temple of the heavens".

*honestas* and *decor* are the subject of sacrarunt. Therefore, it says:

...whom the honesty of life, and the propriety of loyalty, consecrated among the divine powers of the temple of the heavens...

*Expertem* modifies *quem*, the subject of the stanza (*ille*). *gravis ambitus* is in the genitive and is the classification of Expertem (destitute of...). *ambitus* literally means something canvassed. To canvas means to walk around and petition people. By extension it means any perimeter. In Christian theology it refers to the "compass of the heavens". In other words, the sun and the planets revolve around the earth, so they constitute the perimeter of the universe. Hence, in theology the *ambitus* is the cosmos. However, here, the word is being used metaphorically. Erasmus described Satan as *auctor ambitus iniqui* (the author of sinful pride). So, in other words, Erasmus characterizes Satan as the wonted ambitus---somebody who wants to possess the whole universe. Thus, in Catholic ideology, the term *ambitus* signifies the cardinal sin of **Pride**. Hence, altogether the stanza reads literally as follows:

```
That one dies not lamentable to anyone,
     Whom honesty of life, and propriety of loyalty,
     Have consecrated among the divine powers of the Temple of the Heavens,    
     (Who is) Destitute of oppressive pride.
```

or more figuratively,

```
He dies not lamented by anyone,
Whom honesty of life, and propriety of loyalty,
Have consecrated among the divine powers of the Temple of the Heavens,
One destitute of oppressive pride.
```

Comment: *Cuiquam* is a dative of reference (or a dative of (dis)advantage, if you prefer), not an agent, and *ambitus* just meant 'vanity' in Classical Latin as well—your attempt to connect it to the cosmos is unnecessary (and you yourself must realise that it's unsupportable). It's not really pride as a cardinal sin (typically *superbia*), but it's similar, obviously. I'd say you've basically got it otherwise.

Comment: @Cairnarvon I did not mean to imply that *cuiquam* was Dative of Agent, I simply said "agent of flebilis" meaning the one doing the lamenting. I know that *ambitus* could mean vanity in the classical period, but my understanding is that extending its use for Pride, specifically, was an invention of Erasmus. The difference between pride and vanity is that vanity is caring what other people think of you, but pride is what you think of yourself. In the theology of Erasmus, Pride is one of the seven deadly sins, but vanitas is only a secondary sin.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Concerning the use of *ambitus* to signify the sin of Pride specifically as terminology, see commentaries on the *Paean Divae Mariae* for example.

Comment: Thanks. that's helpful. I got *occidit* wrong (thinking it comes from the real active occīdō). also this *sacrarunt* just after *inter* was a source of confusion to me.  About the influence from Erasmus, it should be noted this poem was probably written between 1500-1507 when Erasmus was in his 30s.  It makes the Erasmus connection less plausible.

Comment: @d_e It is possible that the idea of Pride as a cardinal sin predates him. I am just trying to give a sense for some of the theology involved. The key thing is to reallze that in this context, *ambitus* refers to *superbia* rather than *vanitas*.

Comment: @TylerDurden, It is just the case that strong claims/assertions deserve strong evidence. To say that "ambitus signifies the cardinal sin of Pride" is a strong claim. On the face of it, I would say the term *ambitus gravis* is rare, and I do find the adjective *gravis* makes it much less probable that *ambitus*  in this context is a specific refence to something.

Comment: @d_e I already cited evidence above: commentaries on the Paean Divae Mariae. Also, you can read other scholars who specialize in Erasmus or 15th century Catholic theology in general, especially with respect to the cardinal sins. Also, as I wrote early Erasmus specifically calls Satan "auctor ambitus iniqui" and this can only mean superbia, because that is Satan's sin, not vanitas.

Comment: *Caelitum* is genitive plural. The phrase *numina caelitum* is much more a callback to classical imagery (typical of the Renaissance) than traditionally Christian imagery. I would also translate *expers* in a less strong way, e.g. "who had no part in grave ambition."

Comment: I can't find the commentary you're referring to, but *superbia* has always been the traditional word for pride (Cassian, Aquinas, Dante, every stained-glass window I've seen--to name a few). Erasmus himself uses *ambitus/ambire* in the "ambition" sense in his *Encomium Moriae*, where he also uses *superbia* to mean pride. Point being: if you think it specifically means pride, I'd appreciate a quote that shows that. Otherwise, great translation