# Does Latin Word "honestus" Mean English Word "honest"?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

In Latin there are words which look & sound English-y; but, do not mean the English things which they resemble e.g. Latin word, "infestus", does not mean English, "infested"; but, "hostile". There is a possible linkage: a body which is doing the infesting may well be hostile. Still, the meanings are not synonymous. Similarly, Latin word, "insecto", does not mean English, "insect"; but, is a verb: "to pursue with hostile intent". Again, there is a linkage: picture a squadron of angry wasps pursuing clumsy character who has disturbed their nest.

And, Latin word, "honestus", does it mean honest? In Q: https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/18854/1982, Tyler Durden made this translation:

> "quem vitae honestas, et fidei decor," =

> "Whom honesty of life and propriety of loyalty,"

The sources: Oxford, Wiki, L&S: none of these state, "honest"; but "honourable", "noble", "of high rank", and other laudable things. It may well be that people possessing these qualities are honest; but, these are not synonymous terms, are they?

Interesting, in the English-Latin section of Oxford, "honest" is given as, "probus"; "sincerus"; "integer"; but, not, "honestus".

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please note that English *insect* comes straight from Latin *(animal) insectum*, from *insecare* (to cut in, quia corpora horum animalium insecta videntur). It is completely unrelated to *insector*.

Comment: Note also that in *vitae honestas*, the *honestas* is not a form of *honestus*, but a third-declension noun *honestas, -tatis, f.*

Comment: Serious question: if you don't trust the standard dictionaries why would you trust us?

Comment: I think Tyler's translation is accurate enough. You could argue that "honorability of life" would be more accurate, but it does not sound idiomatic to me.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Thanks for clearing these things up. The Q. was predicated on the (potential) confusion for (native) English-speakers generated by English-sounding words, hence the inclusion of, "insecto". I wondered why TD had used a feminine, accusative plural (honestas). It was almost my next Q!

Comment: @Cairnarvon: Of course I trust dictionaries; but, apart from L&S, they don't always provide context. Therefore, students sometimes choose the wrong word for a given circumstance. Dictionaries provide guidance and the student still needs to think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is probably not much to add to the dictionaries. *Honestus* does not mean “free of fraud, lies or deception,” so if that's what you think of when you hear the English word *honest*, well, that's not it. It does indeed mean something like “honourable,” and arguably dishonesty is also dishonourable, so a *vir honestus* can certainly be expected to keep to the truth, but that is just one aspect of his virtues, and the Latin word does not single it out.

Note that besides the excellence of someone's character, *honestus* can also refer to the honours bestowed on him, or the high esteem in which he is held.

Note also that the English word *honest* also has a broader meaning than just “truthful.” According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/honest), it also means “reputable, respectable,” and also “good, worthy.” In this sense it can be translated as *honestus*.

Comment: Yep, an "honest living" is a respectable living, not one free of lies, although the two ideas are related.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: If we wish to say that someone tells the truth we state it: "He tells the truth/ doesn't tell lies,"; similarly, with the others, "He is respectable,", not, "He is honest," in the forlorn hope that this whole string of adjectives will be understood. Use of "honest": this person won't steal your possessions; will keep promises/ deals; will honour contractual obligations, even when it may be inconvenient to do so ("He has integriity," would be far better for these; "honourable" = Latin, "honestus".

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Consider: criminals have codes of honour: silence, loyalty; but, they are not honest. It is possible to be honourable without being honest. Is this why Latin, "honestus" does not mean "honest"?